# EXCEL Index match not showing results for other date

Tags: microsoft-excel, search-indexing

The project is a reservation calendar.

I have a table for input (dates, wish house, and morning or afternoon).

Then based on this table it shows in the calendar if it is free or reserved with the name of the person.

I have a `INDEX()` `MATCH()` formula but the calendar doesn't show if there is a reservation on same day.

How can I fix this?

Formula on cell S10 is:

```
=SI.ND(SI(INDICE(Tabla1;COINCIDIR(R10;Tabla1[Fecha];0);2)="x";
INDICE(Tabla1;COINCIDIR(R10;Tabla1[Fecha];0);10);"");"")
```

[image: Image calendar reservation]

Comment: What do you expect it to return?

Comment: Generally, INDEX/MATCH will only return the first matching value. You'll have to update the formula (or use an alternative formula) to get All matching values. Beyond this, your formula will also have to convert ALL matching rows into one resultant row. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood correctly, then you might be trying to accomplish the following, refer the screenshot :

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>S10</kbd>

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Table1[Nombre],
  MATCH(1,(INDEX(Table1[[M1]:[T4]],,
  MATCH(S$9,Table1[[#Headers],[M1]:[T4]],0))="x")*($R10=Table1[Fecha]),0)),"")
```

---

Equivalent Spanish Version will be :

```
=SI.ERROR(INDICE(Table1[Nombre];
  COINCIDIR(1;(INDICE(Table1[[M1]:[T4]];;
  COINCIDIR(S$9;Table1[[#Encabezados];[M1]:[T4]];0))="x")*($R10=Table1[Fecha]);0));"")
```

---

The above formula needs to be filled down and works across `Excel 2010`+ onwards, however it needs to hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> based on ones Excel Version, `Excel 2021+` onwards users don't require.

---

`XLOOKUP()` can also be used which works with `Execl 2021+` onwards:

```
=XLOOKUP(1,(FILTER(Table1[[M1]:[T4]],S$9=Table1[[#Headers],[M1]:[T4]])="x")*($R10=Table1[Fecha]),Table1[Nombre],"")
```

---

If you are using `MS365` then use `MAKEARRAY()` to spill all at once using one single dynamic array formula:

```
=MAKEARRAY(ROWS(R10:R31),COLUMNS(S9:Z9),LAMBDA(r,c,
  XLOOKUP(1,(FILTER(Table1[[M1]:[T4]],INDEX(S9:Z9,c)=Table1[[#Headers],[M1]:[T4]])="x")*
  (INDEX(R10:R31,r)=Table1[Fecha]),Table1[Nombre],"")))
```

---

However, all the mentioned above formulas certainly will not work if two persons reservations falls on same date for same bungalows etc. For that, the formula will be different, refer the screenshot below,

[image]

---

```
=TEXTJOIN(", "&CHAR(10),1,REPT(Table1[[Nombre]:[Nombre]],
 (FILTER(Table1[[M1]:[T4]],S$9=Table1[[#Headers],[M1]:[T4]])="x")*
 ($R10=Table1[[Fecha]:[Fecha]])))
```

---

The above formula needs to fill down and fill right!

Comment: Thank you for the response. Thats the solution I searched for. Sorry i did not attach the example file. Will use your post reference and learn. Thank you.

Comment: @erichnagy glad to know it worked for you.